# Server suddenly send Fin Push Ack

Tags: java, tcp

I have a java application client that connect to server through socket .
They both correctly for a while but suddenly server sends [FP.] Flag.and our client side answer [P.] , then the server goes for Reset Flag([R]).

Could anyone help me to find the reason why?

Comment: Please provide some relevant code snippets - otherwise it is hard to help.

Comment: Most likely is that the server closed the socket, resulting in the server sending the FIN.  From a TCP standpoint, the socket is now "half closed" meaning that the server is done sending data, however, since the server has closed the socket, it can no longer receive data from the client.  When data arrives from the client, the TCP stack can't deliver it to the application and sends a RST.  See, e.g., https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/articles/connection_release.html

Comment: Thanks for reply , another question ... Is there any chance to find the problem in OS level. i mean os tunning can help to cover the problem?

Comment: Since it seems the server has closed the connection, if the client continues to send data, there is nothing the OS can do about it, which is why it sends a RST. If you didn't expect the server to close the socket, you need to understand why it did and fix that.  If you really want the server to indicate it is done writing but continue to read from the client it should call `shutdownOutput()` rather than `close()`.  Note that this puts the connection into a "half closed" state, and proxies, firewalls and OSs all place limits on how long a connection can remain half closed.

Comment: Also note that since you are the author of the question you will get notified of comments.  If you want to reply to a comment, you will find it helpful to mention the commenter in your reply (e.g. @ysrb) so that they will get a notification.